# How can I recreate MnSymbol's \udotdot command without using MnSymbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

MnSymbol has a `\udotdot` command ([search for `\udotdot` in the comprehensive latex symbol list document](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)), but I don't want to import MnSymbol because of all the side-effects (for instance, it creates `\vec` definitions that clash with other `\vec` definitions, and its meant to be used with Adobe Minion Pro in particular).

How can I create my own `\udotdot` symbol, for use with Computer Modern or Concrete Math?

Comment: You can pull a single symbol from another font. See [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: @Werner but it *will* look weird compared to the the Computer Modern beside it, no?

Comment: i don't believe this symbol is in unicode.  what is its meaning, please, and can you provide a reference to its use in a publication from an established publisher, preferably in a context that defines its scope of application?  i will be happy to propose it for unicode, but solid documentation is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example uses the normal dot to generate the symbol:

- `\mathpalette` adds support for the different math styles.
- It is assumed, that the dot is on the base line with a correct character
  bounding box including symmetrical side bearings. The dot itself has the same width and height.
- The two dots of `\udotdot` lie on opposite corners of a square, which
  is centered around the math axis.
- The centers of the dots lie on the upper and lower borders of the equals sign.

Implementation with example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\udotdot}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\@udotdot{}}%
}
\providecommand*{\@udotdot}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  % Box 0: dot
  \sbox0{$#1.\m@th$}%
  % Remove side bearings
  \setbox2=\hbox to \ht0{\hss\copy0\hss}
  % Side bearing
  \dimen2=.5\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  % Box 2: equal sign
  \sbox4{$#1=\m@th$}%
  % Box 4: math axis
  \sbox6{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr(\ht4-\ht6)*2 + \ht0\relax
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing
  \vcenter to \dimen@{%
    \hbox to \dimen@{\hfill\copy2}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vfill
    \hbox to \dimen@{\copy2\hfill}%
  }%
  \kern\dimen2 % side bearing
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ a \udotdot b \]
\[={\udotdot}\scriptstyle{\udotdot}\scriptscriptstyle{\udotdot}=\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks very much for this generous answer. In order to be able to make my own operator symbols in the future (i.e. fully understand what you just did), are there a resources you'd recommend I familiarze myself with?

Comment: @user89 Further readings: The TeXbook by Donald E. Knuth or [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) by Victor Eijkhout.

Answer (score 3):

You can either [import the single MnSymbol symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764), or create one that roughly matches it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\udotdot}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{${\cdot}{\cdot}$}}}}
\begin{document}

$a \cdots e \cdot a \mathbin{\cdot\cdot} e \mathbin{{\cdot}{\cdot}} a \udotdot e$

$a \udotdot e_{a \udotdot e_{a \udotdot e}}$

\end{document}​
```

Comment: smart....the rotatebox command comes from graphicx?

Comment: @user89: Yes, and [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` ensure the appropriate size of the eventual `\cdot`-pair that is rotated.